# Improving Javascript performance by wrapping and reducing executed statements

Tags: javascript

I am doing a website. Many pages depend on Javascript. At this moment, I have individual Javascript files (many are quite large) for respective pages. The following is an example for one individual Javascript file for a particular page (suppose this page has `<body id="page_1">`):

```
$('#id_1').click(function(e) {
   ...
});
$('#id_2').click(function(e) {
   ...
});
....
$('#id_N').click(function(e) {
   ...
});
...
//there can be many functions like this one
function abc() {
}
```

For website performance, I am going to combine all these individual Javascript files into one file. Before doing this, I am going to wrap each Javascript file to make it only applicable to its target page in the following way (adding an IF statement):

```
if ($('#page_1').length > 0) {

    $('#id_1').click(function(e) {
       ...
    });
    $('#id_2').click(function(e) {
       ...
    });
    ....
    $('#id_N').click(function(e) {
       ...
    });
    ...
    //there can be many functions like this one
    function abc() {
    }
}
```

I think this can help in three ways in case of a combined Javascript file:

1. Reduce potential conflict with other individual Javascript files
2. Reduce the possibility of affecting html elements on other pages
3. Improve the speed of processing the combined Javascript file because the browser will not have to execute many statements not applicable for a page.

Am I right in these points? Hope to hear from experts out there so that I can do the right thing.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: While it should not strictly impact processing speed if the same logic is applied in the end, loading time and parsing time will take quite the hit.

Comment: Kyll, thanks for your input. I am a bit confused by "take quite the hit". What I plan to do is a good thing or bad thing?

Comment: I meant that if instead of loading one JavaScript file per page, users have to download all the files for each page, the first load will take more time. Caching should be your friend after that.

Comment: Thanks for your follow-up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1 and #2 depends on your code, but about #3 it would be a small increase in loading speed, yes. Very, very small though since looking up selectors is blazing fast and if the selector doesn't match anything, all functions applied on it won't execute.